# Can i search in Elasticsearch by one field and range by another, using GET without body?

Tags: elasticsearch, range

How correct write query is such case?

http://host:9200/some_logs/_search?q=field_id:64936&sort=timestamp:asc&size=1000&timestamp[1458831534.6699+TO+9458831534.6699]&pretty

I just want find documents with some field_id that have timestamp more than some timestamp. And i want do it in browser.

Comment: What is the error you are getting using the query that you have used?

Comment: No any error. Output just the same if i use request without range:

http://host:9200/some_logs/_search?q=field_id:64936&sort=timestamp:asc&size=1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple fields in the query URI. Please try the query as below.

http://host:9200/some_logs/_search?q=%2Bfield_id%3A64936+%2Btimestamp%3A[1458831534+TO+9458831534]&sort=timestamp%3Aasc&size=1000&pretty

Note :

- `timestamp` is supposed to be mapped as a `date` field
- %2B is decoded as '+' and '+' is decoded as ' '

Comment: Yes, thanks, its exactly what i want and its works well.